# mcimagemanager jump to last textarea

Tags: tinymce, mcimagemanager

I setup 2 text input which make use of javascript:mcImageManager.open and 2 textarea which load the tinymce richtext editor. when I click on the first text input on the top and load the imagemanager , without doing anything just click on the close button, the cursor will jump to the last textarea.

attach with a sample http://imknight.webfactional.com/ , click on the first text input image icon , then close it, cursor jump to the last textarea.

Comment: +1 for a sample, but when i click on the button i get "mcImageManager is not defined "

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "No, i do not have this problem".

You did not ask for a solution to your problem.